# How can I return the cloned element from this jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Here's what i have:

```
jQuery.fn.convertInputType = function(t){
  var e = this;
  e.each(function(i){
    var o = jQuery(this)
    ,   c = o.clone();
    c.attr('type',t);
    o.replaceWith(c);
  });
  return e;
}
```

I can't figure out what to return back out to make it chain, like:

```
$('.example').convertInputType('password').css('background','blue');
```

I thought i could build an array like `newReturnObj[i] = o.replaceWith(c)` or `newReturnObj[i] = c` or `newReturnObj[i] = jQuery(c)`, but none work.

Comment: Btw the method name is quite long... how about `setType`?

Comment: setType just worries me that it's too vague and also "setting type" is the same as "type setting" means settings font styles. I was actually going to use it, but was worried about it on a massive code base with ~150 engineers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, this works:

```
$.fn.convertInputType = function ( type ) {  

    // we use .map() because we're replacing the set of elements  
    return this.map( function ( i, elem ) {
        var clone = $( this ).clone().attr( 'type', type );        
        $( this ).replaceWith( clone );        
        return clone[0];
    });  

};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qTqQr/1/

Comment: `jQuery('#invitations-by_email').find('.email.partial').css('background','red').convertInputType('password').css('background','green');` The inputs never turn green :(